# A better way to write a multi-dimensional array php

Tags: php

I am looking for a better understanding on how I can stack arrays more efficiently possibly using a `while` loop?

I have this old array that I need to iterate through, explode each, and create a multi-dimensional array. Is there a better way to do this programatically?

```
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear"; 
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear/Men&#39;s"; 
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear/Men&#39;s/Apparel"; 
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear/Men&#39;s/Footwear"; 
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear/Men&#39;s/Accessories";

foreach($cat as $cs){
    $ex = explode("/",$cs);
    $count = count($ex);
    if($count == 1){
        $category[$ex[0]] = array();
    }
    if($count == 2){
        $category[$ex[0]][$ex[1]] = array();
    }
    if($count == 3){
        $category[$ex[0]][$ex[1]][$ex[2]] = array();
    }
    if($count == 4){
        $category[$ex[0]][$ex[1]][$ex[2]][$ex[3]] = array();
    }
    if($count == 5){
        $category[$ex[0]][$ex[1]][$ex[2]][$ex[3]][$ex[4]] = array();
    }
}
```

The issue is that even though there are only a max of 3 array pieces per iteration, this could be more but I don't want to manually create `if($count == x…` I need this to be dynamic. There must be a better way?

Comment: If you are just hard-coding the "old" array, why not simply hard-code a more appropriate array structure?

Comment: I know it sounds old tech but the reason is because I am really creating this output from another database written in ASP.NET MVC and only have this type of solution available so I'm stuck with that structure.

Comment: If the data resides in a DB, then you just need to query it properly and read it into the proper data structure to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `&` modifier to [set variables by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) rather than by value. Effectively this means that the variable **is** the other variable - another reference to it. By tracking the "root" object and iterating over the array that results from the `explode()` you can map into the `$category` array to set as many levels as are needed.

```
$cat = array();
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear"; 
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear/Men&#39;s"; 
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear/Men&#39;s/Apparel"; 
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear/Men&#39;s/Footwear"; 
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear/Men&#39;s/Accessories";

// initialize array to track categories
$category = array();
// keep track of the root so we can reset it after each loop
$root = &$category;
foreach( $cat as $cs ){
    $exes = explode( "/", $cs );
    foreach ( $exes as $ex ){
        // get rid of spaces
        $ex = trim( $ex );
        // if this element isn't set at this level, add it
        if ( ! isset( $category[$ex] ) ){
            $category[$ex] = array();
        }
        // map down a level for the next loop
        $category = &$category[$ex];
    }
    // reset back to the $root for the next $cat
    $category = &$root;
}

var_dump( $category );
```

This will result in array with the following structure, or see it [running in this CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rFOZPR).

```
array(1) {
  ["Apparel, accessories & footwear"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Men's"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["Apparel"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["Footwear"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["Accessories"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to learn, setting variables by reference.  Much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

untested code:

```
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear"; 
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear/Men&#39;s"; 
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear/Men&#39;s/Apparel"; 
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear/Men&#39;s/Footwear"; 
$cat[] = "Apparel, accessories & footwear/Men&#39;s/Accessories";

foreach($cat as $cs){
    $ex = explode("/",$cs);
    $count = count($ex);

    $ptr = &$category;
    for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
       $ptr = &$ptr[$ex[$i]];
    } 

    $ptr = array();

}
```

Comment: yean, that's not going to run.

Comment: Actually $ptr = array(); at the end empties the array. but if I comment it out, seems like the array is writing over the last array set so by the end the array in 0 is empty.

Comment: i i said untested code :) 
i don't have the PC here now, but that's the idea